# too much loading time in nextjs

Tags: reactjs, next.js, frontend

[image]I'm new to Nextjs. I have implemented a page. The SSR is used. But as you can see in the picture, there are a lot of workboxes running, each lasting 100 to 300 milliseconds, and this has increased the load time.
[image]

Comment: Check your image size, maybe?

Comment: @RyanLe If the author is using next's image component then it's already using the smallest size

Comment: I see, The image shows all the requests are in parallel within "only" 300ms. I guess it's totally acceptable

Comment: @RyanLe but I'm using image CDN

Comment: All of them are js. And with that amount of loading time, while they are all loading parallelly, You don't have to worry about it. Do you visually see it's slow?

Comment: perhaps use the lighthouse tool to check where the issue is

Answer (score 1):

I see your problem. You are loading all the Image and Product Components at once, so the entire website is lagging. You have to split the search, maybe 10 to 15 products per viewport, and when user scrolls through the end, load the next 10 to 15 products and so on.

you can use useEffect with useState to do so.

Also, adjust the API to fetch limited data at times,

i.e:

https://api.com/getproducts?quantity=10

Comment: I did everything you said, there is only one problem, and that is that for every card that contains s image and text, I have a component called ProductCard. There are 12 ProductCard that are mapped on the page and I don't know how to use them in view to avoid generate that cards that aren't in view. More precisely:
{productList?.map((item) => ( <ProductCard {...item} /> ))}

Comment: You can use Infinite Scroll Component for react

Comment: Also Point to be noted, you are using SSR, so the page is first being converted to plain HTML in server and then served, meaning the HTML is huge and that is why it is slower. Instead of using Server Side Fetching, use the useEffec() directly in the component and fetch data in the client side